# rebuilding dbxopenmysql50 project

Tags: mysql, delphi

https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co...d_mysql_5.html
Just software gives out free Delphi dbxopenmysql50.dll code of the project. One of the files SqlxApi.pas contains only some types of data But MySQL 5.7 has moved on with more datatypes.
  I'm wanting to rebuild it with the new datatypes added but do not have the info from Oracle to do so. Just software are more than happy for someone to continue the project. Does any one know where I could get such info as I can build the dll in Delphi 7 and test it. I want to rename it dbxopenmysql57.dll and give respect to Just software for their work.